# How to insert a variable inside a json url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use my defined var inside the json url:

```
var articleName = "test";

$.getJSON( "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_MY&cx=CX_MY&q='+articleName+'&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=xlarge&alt=json`",
```

I tried: `q='+articleName+'` but it's wrong

Comment: You need to use matching quotes.

Comment: String literals are just strings. They aren't parsed as code.

Comment: @SLaks i tried "'+articleName+'"

Comment: Just use `"` before and after `+`, like `&q='"+articleName+"'&`

Comment: As much as I would appreciate people answering, it's a simple string concatenation problem. Please just try to debug a problem for a little longer which'll definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `"` before and after `+`, like `&q='"+articleName+"'&`

Another solution is using `data`

Option 1: Just for article name

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_MY&cx=CX_MY&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=xlarge&alt=json",{
    "q":articleName
},
```

Option 2: All param

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1",{
    "q"          : articleName,
    "alt"        : "json",
    "imgSize"    : "xlarge",
    "fileType"   : "jpg",
    "searchType" : "image",
    "cx"         : "CX_MY",
    "key"        : "API_MY"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
var params = {
 key1: val1,
 key2: val2
};

$.getJSON( "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", params, function(res) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`"some " + yourVar + " text"`

or

`'some ' + yourVar + ' text'`

or use template literals (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON( "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_MY&cx=CX_MY&q="+articleName+"&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=xlarge&alt=json`"`